# Non-Winclone Boot Camp backup solution

Tags: macos, backup, bootcamp, windows, partition

I have an 11,3 i7 iMac, from around 2010. I want to upgrade to Mavericks and do a clean install of both Mavericks and Windows 7 in Boot Camp - reformat the internal HD and repartition.

I need a solution for backing up my Windows user files - documents, some apps if possible - but I don't need an actual image of my old partition. I did pick up a copy of Winclone and I'm running it, but the backup process is incredibly slow. Check out these timestamps!

```
26-03-14 02:37:28   Winclone[6116]  53.51 percent completed
26-03-14 03:06:37   Winclone[6116]  54.52 percent completed
26-03-14 03:37:34   Winclone[6116]  55.53 percent completed
26-03-14 04:13:04   Winclone[6116]  56.54 percent completed
26-03-14 04:46:15   Winclone[6116]  57.55 percent completed
```

Is there any alternative to Winclone (I refuse to believe that imaging a 250GB partition requires a fifty-hour period) and is there some way I could simply back up my Windows files instead of the whole partition? I know the two filesystems are different, so it cannot be as simple as simply dragging the files from the Boot Camp partition to my external 3TB Seagate?

Comment: Yes it is. You can backup your Windows files to your external 3TB Seagate IF it is NTFS, FAT32, or exFAT. Just drag and drop the files onto the Seagate.

Answer (score 1):

Any Windows Backup software of your choice. Altho you then might have to reinstall windows before you can restore the files themself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to back up files is to create a Windows partition (Fat, NTFS, or ExFat) on your back-up drive.  Then simply copy the files you wish to save into that patition.

Be careful when using backup software made for Windows.  Most are not designed for use on a disk which was not formatted using Windows.

One of the more popular Windows backup programs, Acronis True-Image, doesn't even work on boot-camp.  At least I couldn't get the 2011 version to work.